# Not receiving the complete data from Arduino via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

This is my Arduino code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int bluetoothTx = 11;
int bluetoothRx = 12;

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  //Read from bluetooth and write to usb serial
  if(bluetooth.available()) {
    char tosend = (char)bluetooth.read();
    Serial.print(tosend);
    if (tosend == '1') {
      Serial.println("Hello");
      bluetooth.println("Hellllo");
    }
  }
}
```

On Android I have this function:

```
public void run() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
    int bytes = 0; // bytes returned from read()

    // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
    while (true) {
        try {
            // Read from the InputStream
            bytes = mInStream.read(buffer);
            // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, e.toString());
            break;
        }
    }
 }
```

The second thing is that even though I haven't written a delay, my output on Android is split in a thread. Please help.

Comment: Can you share arduino name.Can you also share contents of buffer?

Comment: Some time it shows me "h" then shows "ello" . that is not fixed "he","llo" like this also and ardiuno uno i have used n hc_05

Comment: Alright if you are receiving ello that may suggest that you do not have a issue in communication (could have been weird hex values) Now 2 sources are arduino sending data partially or android app is parsing data wrong. Can you log buffer ? Also Can you change string length and verify again ?

Comment: i got the solution thing was that I was sending the data that time only i was receving the data as the data was just coming from bluetooth slowly there the problem occurs . \n so what i did to solve the issue was by making the thread sleep for few second then i got the complete output  .. Finnallly

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution thing was that I was sending the data that time only i was receving the data as the data was just coming from bluetooth slowly there the problem occurs . \n so what i did to solve the issue was by making the thread sleep for few second then i got the complete output .. Finnallly